# Can I "dynamically" deserialize subtypes with newtonsoft json

Tags: c#, json.net

I would like to deserialize a "recursive" "$typed" datastructure. I've gotten to the point where I can deserialise the top level object, but I hop the deserializer can be instructed to deserialize sub objects as well.

// JSon I'd like to deserialize:

```
{
    "$type": "Sd.SmoothUnion,  Assembly-CSharp",
    "one": {
        "$type": "Sd.Sphere,  Assembly-CSharp",
        "offset": [0,0,0],
        "rotation":[0,0,0],
        "radius": 2
    },
    "two": {
        "$type": "Sd.SmoothUnion, Assembly-CSharp",
        "one": {
            "$type": "Sd.Sphere, Assembly-CSharp",
            "offset": [0,0,0],
            "rotation":[0,0,0],
            "radius": 2
        },
        "two": {
            "$type": "Sd.Sphere, Assembly-CSharp",
            "offset": [0,2,0],
            "rotation":[0,0,0],
            "radius": 2
        },
        "smooth": 0.8   
    },
    "smooth": 0.8   
}
```

When I deserialize this, I do get a SmoothUnion instance, but properties "one" and "two" are null.

All objects should conform to an interface, but are defined in their own class.

The tree of objects might grow deeper then 2.

// Interface:

```
public interface SDFObject
{
    string getFunction();
}
```

// SmoothUnion:

```
namespace Sd
{
    public class SmoothUnion : SDFObject
    {
        SDFObject one;
        SDFObject two;
        float smooth;

        public string getFunction()
        {
            return "This is a Smooth Union!";
        }
    }
}
```

// Sphere:

```
namespace Sd
{
    public class Sphere : SDFObject
    {
        List<int> offset;
        List<int> rotation;
        int radius;

        public string getFunction()
        {
            return "This is a Sphere!";
        }
    }
}
```

//Deserializer

```
object o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
    MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.ReadAhead
});
SDFObject s = (SDFObject)o;
```

Is there an easy config I missed, or can you recommend some examples?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to make the fields public.
There may be better solutions, but the problem had nothing to do with the type inference.

Comment: If you don't want to make your fields or properties public you can add the `[JsonProperty]` attribute with desired name to it and it will be de-/ serialized regardless of its visibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make fields public, solution here is to use custom [JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm)

You would simply override `CanConvert()` and `ReadJson()` for `SmoothUnion` and `Sphere`

```
   public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(SmoothUnion).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

   public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        var su = new SmoothUnion();
        su.smooth = (float)obj["smooth"];
        su.one = obj["one"].ToObject<SDFObject>(serializer);
        su.two = obj["two"].ToObject<SDFObject>(serializer);
        return su;
    }
```

and use it like

```
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.ReadAhead,
            Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new SmoothUnionConverter(), new SphereConverter() }
        };

        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, settings);
```

P.S

Simpler approach is to use `[JsonProperty]` attribute, but not sure if it works on your case.

Hope this helps.